# C# ввод неизвестного числа строк

Tags: c#, while

Проблема в том, что блок кода хоть и рабочий, но остановка цикла происходит при повторном нажатии Enter

```
            var output = new List<string>();
            
            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            {
                output.Add(Decoder(line));
                line = Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

Как это переписать так, чтобы не требовалось повторное нажатие?

Comment: Попросить один раз `Console.ReadLine()`, а потом уже крутить цикл? Вы ведь сами каждую итерацию запрашиваете ввод....

Comment: Я пробовал переписать на while `while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line = Console.ReadLine()))` , но результат тот же

Comment: И почему он тот же вы не поняли? Цикл постоянно проверяет условие, которое вы ему задаете, каждую итерацию. Повторю - один раз попросите, за пределами цикла, а уже потом в цикле крутите все, что надо.

Comment: Я поимаю что происходит, но роблема в том, что не знаю как сделать такой ввод именно в C#

Comment: Так, еще раз опишите что хотите видеть, и в чем конкретно проблема? Что значит "повторное нажатие"? А то что-то я запутался немного. Сейчас ваш код должен работать так: написали 1, добавило, 2, добавило, 3, добавило, нажали просто ввод, вышло из цикла. Если вам не нравится последний шаг, то как вы без ввода от пользователя узнаете, пустота там или нет? А вообще, яб на вашем месте заменил это на `do/while` цикл.